# How to get the length of an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to convert some jQuery to javascript. Was using this for jQuery:

```
 var list = $('.list li'),
     listLength = list.length;
```

Now I'm trying it with JS, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 var list = document.querySelector(".list"),
     listLi = list.getElementsByTagName("li"),
     listLength = listLi.length;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works just fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/gWvCQ/

Comment: Your Vannila JS code works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, just had a typo in the actual code. Oops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should already work. But you can also use `document.querySelectorAll()` to perform a selector match which is cleaner than the two separate calls:

```
var listLi = document.querySelectorAll(".list li"),
    listLength = listLi.length;
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it's only supported in IE9+

Comment: Not mentioned as a requirement in the question :) But you could shim it anyway